# Prove eigenfunctions corresponding to different eigenvalues are orthogonal

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, eigenfunctions

I'm considering the eigenvalue problem $L(\phi) = -\lambda \sigma(x) \phi$, subject to a given set of homogeneous boundary conditions.  Assume $\sigma(x) \gt 0$ on an interval $[a,b]$.

Suppose that $\int_{a}^{b} [uL(v) - vL(u)]dx = 0$ for all functions $u$ and $v$ satisfying the same homogeneous boundary conditions.

How can I prove that two eigenfunctions corresponding to different eigenvalues $\lambda_1 \ne \lambda_2$ are orthogonal with respect to some choice of weight?

Comment: What is $L$? What are the conditions? What is the space?

Comment: The conditions aren't given. I don't think they're necessary

Comment: Yes, they are important. Orthogonality of eigenfunctions for different eigenvalues requires some kind of symmetry, and the right kind of endpoint conditions.

Comment: In this case the necessary self-adjointness is articulated in the Question, contingent on (unspecified) homogeneous boundary conditions.

Comment: @user274933: The one detail of your Question that needs clarification is the mention of $\sigma(x)$ in formulating(?) "the eigenvalue problem".  If this is removed, it becomes a simple problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be helpful to understand the similar fact about left and right eigenvectors of a matrix, in order to appreciate the role being played here by self-adjointness of the operator $L$.

In any case the computation is straightforward, applying what we know in the case that $u,v$ are eigenfunctions (satisfying the unspecified but requisite homogeneous boundary conditions) corresponding to distinct eigenvalues $\lambda_1 \neq \lambda_2$ respectively:

$$ L(u) = -\lambda_1 \sigma u $$

$$ L(v) = -\lambda_2 \sigma v $$

where multiplier function $\sigma(x)$ on $[a,b]$ must be assumed positive (a.e.) there if we want the natural bilinear function to be an inner product, with the corresponding sense of "orthogonality":

$$ 0 = \int_a^b u L(v) - v L(u) \mathrm{d} x 
     = (\lambda_1 - \lambda_2) \int_a^b u v \; \sigma(x) \mathrm{d} x$$

Since the eigenvalues are unequal, the last integral is zero, and thus $u,v$ are orthogonal with respect to this weighted inner product on $[a,b]$.